# .NET 6.0 FileStream|StreamWriter|BinaryWriter deleting file on .Close() or .Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I'm attempting to simply create a .PNG file from a base64 string.

Initially I was using:

```csharp
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Target\Path\Image.PNG", Convert.FromBase64String(imgData));
```

And this was working locally just fine.  But once deployed to a remote server, I noticed that the resulting .PNG file was missing.

I started to do a little more testing by breaking up the steps to see if I could pinpoint what's going wrong.

I created a test.txt file in the same destination directory as the PNG with some information in it to see if the file would even be created, and it was, using the following code:

```csharp
System.IO.FileStream textfileStream = new FileStream(@"Target\Path\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
System.IO.StreamWriter textfileWriter = new StreamWriter(textfileStream);
textfileWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("[yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm]"));
textfileWriter.WriteLine("This worked!?");

/* fullSigFilename = ~\wwwroot\application\wwwroot\signatures\appsig.png */
textfileWriter.WriteLine($"Path1: {fullSigFilename}");

/* fullSigFilename = ~\wwwroot\application\wwwroot\signatures\adsig.png */
textfileWriter.WriteLine($"Path2: {adFullSigFilename}");

textfileWriter.WriteLine();
textfileWriter.WriteLine($"img contents 1: {imgdata}");
textfileWriter.WriteLine($"img contents 2: {addata}");
textfileWriter.Flush();
textfileWriter.Close();
```

I thought that this was pretty odd.  So I attempted to create my .PNG files with the same, long-winded approach and found that when I called either the .Close() or .Dispose() method, that the resulting physical file was deleted as well!?

Here's the test code for the PNG creation:

```csharp
var sigPNGFS = System.IO.File.Create("Target\Path\sig.PNG");

var sigPNGBW = new BinaryWriter(sigPNGFS);

sigPNGBW.Write(Convert.FromBase64String(imgdata));

sigPNGBW.Flush();

sigPNGBW.Dispose();
```

If I comment out the *.Dispose() line, run the code and then stop the Application Pool, I can open the file just fine in mspaint.

I thought at first that it might possibly be the base64 string causing it to self-destruct, but I can view the file if I don't dispose it, stop the app pool and open it.

Has anyone else ever ran into this issue?

I also removed any try/catch wrapper in order to see if some sort of error would be logged in ~\wwwroot\logs or the Event Viewer, and nothing.

Comment: what is your remove server?

Comment: My inclination would be to investigate the other services running on (or with access to) your server. Perhaps there's a service that watches for a file to be done writing, and performs some kind of process on it? A service like that would want to wait for the file to not have a lock on it anymore. Disposing the binary writer probably disposes the underlying file stream, which releases the lock on the file.

Comment: @NikitaChayka My remote server is a Windows Server 2019 machine running IIS 10.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior This is a brand new application deployed.  Just to make sure I changed the destination directory to a different one in wwwroot and the same issue is occurring.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: A brand-new application, or a brand-new server instance? How did you create the server?

Comment: How are you deploying to the remote server?